# R: What exactly does \ mean in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a very generell question:

What does \ (x) mean?
I know that the x can also be replaced with other letters but I am more wondering, what \ means in R. Because as far as I know \ in my R Version does not work. But when I replace it with function. However, I don't know if \ stands for function.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: According to [R 4.1.0 news](https://cran.r-project.org/) - `R now provides a shorthand notation for creating functions, e.g. \(x) x + 1 is parsed as function(x) x + 1.` If your R version is older than 4.1, it would not work

Comment: ...so, update your R, or, if not possible use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @jay.sf. It's indeed the fact that I have an older version of R.

Comment: Thank you a lot @akrun. It's indeed the fact that I have an older version of R. –

Comment: @akrun Can you find a better dupe?

Comment: @jay.sf it seems fine as it already shows a solution that quotes the R 4.1.